# Vue + MSAL2.x + Azure B2C Profile Editing

Tags: vue.js, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

First, I am not finding Vue specific examples using MSAL 2.x and we'd like to use the PKCE flow. I am having issues with the way the router guards are run before the AuthService handleResponse so I must be doing something wrong.

In my **main.js** I am doing this...

```
// Use the Auth services to secure the site
import AuthService from '@/services/AuthServices';
Vue.prototype.$auth = new AuthService()
```

And then in my **AuthConfig.js** I use this request to login:

```
loginRequest : {
      scopes: [
         "openid", 
         "profile", 
         process.env.VUE_APP_B2C_APISCOPE_READ, 
         process.env.VUE_APP_B2C_APISCOPE_WRITE
      ]
   },
```

The docs say it should redirect to the requesting page but that is not happening. If user goes to the protected home page they are redirected to login. They login, everything is stored properly so they are actually *logged in*, but then they are sent back to the root redirect URL for the site, not the Home page.

When a user wants to login we just send them to the protected home page and there is a login method called in the router guard which looks like this:

```
router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
   const requiresAuth = to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)
   const IsAuthenticated = await Vue.prototype.$auth.isAuthenticated()
   console.log(`Page changing from ${from.name} to ${to.name}, requiresAuth = ${requiresAuth}, IsAuthenticated = ${IsAuthenticated}`)
   if (requiresAuth && !IsAuthenticated) 
   {
     next(false)
     console.log('STARTING LOGIN')
     Vue.prototype.$auth.login()
     // Tried this
     // Vue.prototype.$auth.login(to.path)
   } else {
     next()
   }
 })
```

In **AuthServices.js** I have this...

```
   // The user wants to log in
   async login(nextPg) {

      // Tell B2C what app they want access to and their invitation ID if they are new
      if (store.getters.userEmail != null) {
         aCfg.loginRequest.loginHint = store.getters.userEmail
      }

      aCfg.loginRequest.state = "APP=" + store.getters.appCode
      if (store.getters.appointmentLink != null && store.getters.appointmentLink != '') {
         aCfg.loginRequest.state += ",ID=" + store.getters.appointmentLink
      }

      // Tried this
      // if (nextPg && nextPg != '') {
      //    aCfg.loginRequest.redirectUrl = process.env.VUE_APP_B2C_REDIRECT_URL + nextPg
      // }

      return await this.msalInst.loginRedirect(aCfg.loginRequest)
   }
```

I tried puting a nextPg parameter in the login method and adding a redirectUrl property to the login request but that gives me an error saying it is not one of the configured redirect URLs.

Also, I'm trying to make the user experience better when using the above technologies. When you look at the MSAL2.x SPA samples I see that when returning from a Profile Edit, a user is logged out and they are required to log in again. That sounds like a poor user experience to me. Sample here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-b2c-javascript-spa/blob/main/App/authRedirect.js

Do I need to just create my own profile editing page and save data using MSGraph to prevent that?  Sorry for the noob questions. Ideas?

**Update** - My workaround which seems cheesy is to add these two methods to my AuthService.js:

```
   storeCurrentRoute(nextPath) {
      if (!nextPath) {
         localStorage[STOR_NEXT_PAGE] = router.history.current.path
      } else {
         localStorage[STOR_NEXT_PAGE] = nextPath
      }
      console.log('Storing Route:', localStorage[STOR_NEXT_PAGE])
   }

   reEstablishRoute() {
      let pth = localStorage[STOR_NEXT_PAGE]
      if (!!pth && router.history.current.path != pth) {
         localStorage[STOR_NEXT_PAGE] = ''
         console.log(`Current path is ${router.history.current.path} and reEstablishing route to ${pth}`)
         router.push({ path: pth })
      }
   }
```

I call `storeCurrentRoute()` first thing in the login method and then in the handleResponse() I call `reEstablishRoute()` when its not returning from a profileEdit or password change. Seems like I should be able to make things work without this.

**Update Number Two** - When returning from B2C's ProfileEdit User Flow the MSAL component is not logging me out properly. Here is my code from my `handlePolicyChange()` method in my AuthService:

```
} else if (response.idTokenClaims[clmPolicy] === aCfg.b2cPolicies.names.editProfile) {
         Vue.nextTick(() => {
            console.log('BACK FROM Profile Change')
            Vue.prototype.$swal(
               "Success!",
               "Your profile has been updated.<br />Please log in again.",
               "success"
            ).then(async () => {
               this.logout()
            })
          })

      } 
:
   // The user wants to log out (all accounts)
   async logout() {
      // Removes all sessions, need to call AAD endpoint to do full logout
      store.commit('updateUserClaims', null)
      store.commit('updateUserEmail', null)

      let accts = await this.msalInst.getAllAccounts()
      for(let i=0; i<accts.length; i++) {
         const logoutRequest = {
            account: accts[i],
            postLogoutRedirectUri: process.env.VUE_APP_B2C_REDIRECT_URL
         };
         await this.msalInst.logout(logoutRequest);
      }
      return
   }
```

It is working fine until the call to logout() which runs without errors but I looked in my site storage (in Chrome's debug window > Application) and it looks like MSAL did not clear out its entries like it does on my normal logouts (which always succeed). Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As part of the MSAL auth request, send a `state` Parameter. Base64 encode where the user left off inside this parameter. MSAL exposes `extraQueryParameters` which you can put a dictionary object inside and send in the auth request, put your `state` Key value pair into `extraQueryParameters`.

The `state` param will be returned in the callback response, use it to send the user where you need to.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So just use state instead of local storage...ok. I still need to logout after Profile editing? Because MSAL has the wrong info stored and subsequent API calls fail if I don't, correct?

Comment: Confirmed that using state instead of localStorage is working better. Thanks, Jas

Comment: Returning from ProfileEdit still fails (see my Update #2 above). Thanks

Comment: Actually I was able to make logout work after a profile edit by not including any account on the logoutRequest data.